# XPath Descendant Attribute Filter With Contains

Tags: xml, xpath

Using the XML below, the XPath without `contains` matches 1 element, but one with `contains` matches 0 elements.

```
//pet[@type = "dog"][.//@name = "Acme Dog Food"]
//pet[@type = "dog"][contains(.//@name, "Acme Dog Food")]
```

I would expect both to match the `pet[@name = "Fido"]` element. Why is there a difference?

```
<documentRoot>
<!-- Test data -->
<?value="2"?>
<parent name="data" >
   <child id="1"  name="alpha" >Some Text</child>
   <child id="2"  name="beta" >
      <grandchild id="2.1"  name="beta-alpha" ></grandchild>
      <grandchild id="2.2"  name="beta-beta" ></grandchild>
   </child>
   <pet name="tigger"  type="cat" >
      <data>
         <birthday month="sept"  day="19" ></birthday>
         <food name="Acme Cat Food" ></food>
      </data>
   </pet>
   <pet name="Fido"  type="dog" >
      <description>
         Large dog!
      </description>
      <data>
         <birthday month="feb"  day="3" ></birthday>
         <food name="Acme Dog Food" ></food>
      </data>
   </pet>
   <rogue name="is this real?" >
      <data>
         Hates dogs!
      </data>
   </rogue>
   <child id="3"  name="gamma"  mark="yes" >
      <!-- A comment -->
      <description>
         Likes all animals - especially dogs!
      </description>
      <grandchild id="3.1"  name="gamma-alpha" >
      </grandchild>
      <grandchild id="3.2"  name="gamma-beta" ></grandchild>
   </child>
</parent>
</documentRoot>
```

Online XPath Tester: http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

**XPath 1.0**

When `exp` in `contains(exp, substring)` evaluates to a nodeset, the ***first node's string value*** is used as the first argument to `contains()`.  In your case, the first node of that nodeset is not the 
attribute in this element,

```
<food name="Acme Dog Food" ></food>
```

but rather that `name` attribute in this element

```
<pet name="Fido"  type="dog" >
```

which clearly contains no `"Acme Dog Food"` substring.

**XPath 2.0**

When `exp` in `contains(exp, substring)` evaluates to a sequence of items, an error results.

### Solutions

You can avoid the problem of matching multiple nodes in the first argument of `contains()` by testing the string value of each attribute individually (as already [posted by @DanielHaley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62314583/290085), *please upvote his answer*):

```
//pet[@type = "dog"][.//@name[contains(., "Acme Dog Food")]]
```

You can avoid testing the current node by replacing the `.//` abbreviation for the `descendant-or-self::` axis with just the `descendant::` axis:

```
//pet[@type = "dog"][descendant::*/@name[contains(., "Acme Dog Food")]]
```

Finally, if you don't really need substring checking – if you don't want to match `"Smelly Acme Dog Food"` – use an equality test rather than `contains()`:

```
//pet[@type = "dog"][.//@name = "Acme Dog Food"]
```

as you had in your original XPath.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using XPath 1.0, the `contains(.//@name, "Acme Dog Food")` is only evaluating the first `@name` it finds.

To resolve this, put the "contains" predicate on the attribute:

```
//pet[@type = "dog"][.//@name[contains(., "Acme Dog Food")]]
```

or specify the `food` element:

```
//pet[@type = "dog"][contains(.//food/@name, "Acme Dog Food")]
```

Comment: And we can add `//pet[@type = "dog"][contains((.//@name)[2], "Acme Dog Food")]` too.

Comment: @E.Wiest: We *could*, but such positional dependence is often rather brittle.